# Impala SQL - regexp_like finding exact match

Tags: sql, regex, impala

I'm using regexp_like in Impala to match some strings based off a regex condition.The strings that I want to match follow this format:
RATES.BOND.AUD.ABCDEF
Note: 'ABCDEF' can be any length.

The code is as below:

```
SELECT path
        , regexp_like(path, '^RATES\.BOND\..{3}\..*') as regex
FROM Table1
```

For some reason the above regex is returning 'true' to strings such as:
RATES.BOND_FINANCE.AUD.ABCDEF (the _FINANCE should not be matched)

I've used an online regex checking tool and this should not return as a match.

Can anyone help with this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pls use `split_part`. This will give you fourth string - ABCDEF.

```
select split_part('RATES.BOND.AUD.ABCDEF','.',4)
```

Pls let me know if this helps.